# Why can't I add an object to this array?

Tags: java

```
public class GroceryList {
    //variables
    private int count;
    private Item list[];
    public final int MAX = 30;

    //default
    public GroceryList(){
        Item placeholder1 = new Item();
        Item placeholder2 = new Item();
        list[0] = placeholder1;
        this.count = 0;
    }
}
```

I want to assign the Object placeholder1 to `list[0]` but I get a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Until you assign a value to the array, it doesn't yet exist. It's like having a parking spot -- it's just a spot that fits a car, until you park a car there. You can't tell someone to sit in the driver's seat before there's a car.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array; otherwise, it is `null`.

```
public final int MAX = 30;
private Item[] list = new Item[MAX];
```

Comment: THANK YOU! i can't believe I didn't think of doing that

Comment: @TrevorBollinger No problem.

Comment: @TrevorBollinger Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?